# Complex analysis problem concening the behavior of the derivatives at one point

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic on $\Omega$, prove that there does not exist a point $z_0\in \Omega$, such that for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, such that
$$
|f^{(n)}(z_0)|\ge n!n^n.
$$

Comment: Please give us more information. What tools are you allowed to use? What have you tried?

Comment: @kobe, I tried Cauchy's formular on the upper bound of the derivatives...

Comment: Suppose such a point exists. In a disk centered at $z_0$ in $\Omega$, $f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n (z - z_0)^n$, where $a_n = [f^{(n)}(z_0)]/n!$. Given the assumption on $|f^{(n)}(z_0)|$, what can you say about the radius of convergence of this power series?

Comment: @kobe. Got it. Thanks!